# How to change yii2 Html textinput width

Tags: yii2

How to set size of textInput made through yii\helpers\Html ? Not using ActiveForm,just using Html? I got the input but I want to change its width.

```
<td colspan="5"><?= Html::textInput('comment'); ?></td>
```

Comment: you can try `Html::textInput('comment', 'null', ['width' => '100%' or 'style' => 'width:100');`. [more info](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#textInput%28%29-detail)

Comment: Thanks @InsaneSkull .     this worked for me.  Html::textInput('comment',null,['style'=>'width:300px']);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hii Kartika you can try this, (Hope you inserted '**use yii\helpers\Html;**' in you'r view page)

```
<?php echo  Html::textInput("a",'',['style'=>'width:100%;'])?>
```